# Difference between ,say, "At least 8" and "8 or more"

Tags: soft-question

Are they not the same the thing? Just to be on the safe side I wanted to verify this with others. 
Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Yes, they’re the same.

Comment: This sounds like a question for English Lanugage & Usage or English Language Learners (though don't just take my word for it); it's not really about mathematics.

Comment: Also the same:  "Not less than 8."

Comment: I apologize, I was working on a Binomial distribution problem and assumed the Math would be my go to choice.(It's the only one I use). Next time, I'll post there regarding wording.

Comment: Not necessarily: there can be a difference between plain English usage and mathematical usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean the same thing. Saying "x is at least 8" and "x is 8 or more" are both equivalent to the statement $x \ge 8$.